# UK visit visa refusal - Not sure how to proceed

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

I am wondering if someone can help with this visit visa refusal my Indonesian girlfriend received today

This is a second refusal letter. The first one was refused because we didn't include any proof of relationship and hadn't included the bank where her payroll is paid. Fair enough.

But this one, we included both accounts with 6 months bank statements. The payroll account only contains wages that match her payslips. The savings account (apart from a few payments from me) contains payments from her payroll account.

Everything is accounted for and we even clearly listed all the evidence and my payments in a letter to make it easy for them with a note explaining that the savings account contains payments from the payroll account.

I tried contacting UKIV to tell them and find out what happened but they said they can't help. Should I apply again? Do I need to explain every transaction? How can I make it clearer?

Even though she has plenty of money in her savings account, I still put my myself down as sponsor and that I would pay for flights, accommodation and other expenses. So what's with the last paragraph about working / public funds?

[image]

Comment: It is generally best to provide evidence of the source of every payment into an applicant’s account. Did you submit your bank statements showing the payments from you to your gf? Does this answer your question? [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e)

Comment: @Traveller All. 6 months sponsor, 6 months her savings, 6 months her current (payroll) account. All transactions explained except the payments current -> savings. We thought that was obvious as we had provided both statements and mentioned it in the letter

Comment: When did she apply, when were you intending to travel, for how long, and for what reason? What's your own citizenship and country of residence? Given the current situation, any visa request for tourism purposes or visiting family (and probably many others) will be examined with even more suspicion than usual. It is quite possible that they will take any excuse to reject a visa request.

Comment: @jcaron It looks very much like the OP is in the UK.

Comment: @jcaron UK sponsor, she applied from indonesia 25th nov. travel for 1 month for whole of january.

Comment: Is that the actual letter your girlfriend received? It looks rather strange to me. I would have expected the word UNCLASSIFIED and the version date to be removed, and the blank field for income are definitely odd. If this is the actual document then I'd guess that the wrong letter has been sent.

Comment: it's from the original pdf we received by email, i copied the text into word to remove personal details

Comment: What travel history does your gf have? They seem to think there are other deposits into her account, do you know what they are referring to? Have you seen her bank statements? Why did you put yourself down as sponsoring the cost of the trip, if your gf has enough money to pay for it herself? Having a financial sponsor does tend to weaken an application (hence the ‘no recourse’ reference)

Comment: @Traveller Her travel history is only asia (non visa) countries. Yes I have been through the bank statements. If we had missed something then that would explain the problem. We decided that she would not spend her life savings on this trip, and me paying for the majority of it is simply the truth. We're not going to continue playing the visit visa lottery, and instead focus on a fiance visa later next year. Thanks

Comment: Ah. So she has plenty of money to pay for the trip, but would it drain her savings? Particularly as you've been sending her money.

Comment: she's got about £5000, and I would estimate a mostly self-isolating UK holiday to be about £2000 with the flights, accommodation etc. So no, I wouldn't say that it would "drain" her finances. My understanding is that they assess her finances in case I abandon her as sponsor, they need to ensure she can support herself for the duration of the holiday, which she clearly can.

Comment: @jim smith I’m not sure that’s 100% true. I have successfully sponsored a UK visit visa twice for someone who is completely reliant on me ie has no resources of his own at all. I would imagine that what counted were his ties to home, the length of our relationship and the frequency of my visits to him.